# Using statement with Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, unit-testing

In my application I use Entity Framework and would like to write unit tests.

Uncle Google tells me it's better to use a using-statemant for my dbContext. On the other hand I want to mock my dbContext with Dependency Injection.

How can I solve the problem?

using-statemant:

```
using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                return await db.OrderingEquipments.ToListAsync();
            }
```

dependency injection:

```
        public CupsController(IApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        //_context = obj;
    }
```

Comment: You inject the context where needed, and choose the appropriate lifetime (like for example web request lifetime). At the end of that lifetime, you dispose the context.

Comment: What IoC/DI container are you using?

Comment: Most IoC containers will take care of the disposal for you. No need to use `using`. For example - http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html .

Comment: Be wary of mocking components you don't own. You might be making promises you cannot keep...

Comment: Uncle google isn't a .net expert !! Of course `using` should be used when you are creating new instance, but when you are not creating one, you should not use `using`, here dependency injection container will create instance for you and it is responsibility of the container to dispose, not yours.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a factory contract; example:

```
interface IDbContextProvider
{
    IDbContext Get();
}
```

This is the interface you inject to your consumers. Then you use that provider instance to get the disposable context:

```
CupsController(IDbContextProvider provider)
{
    using (var context = provider.Get()) 
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `IServiceProvider` directly: to create an instance of an class:

```
var context = IServiceProvider.GetType(typeof(IApplicationDbContext));
```

the `IServiceProvider` instance should be inside of your HttpContext where you can access it and create instances of types.

### The EF Dependency Problem

Entity framework needs to be able to create the DbContexts outside the scope of your context to create and execute database migrations with the command line tool they provide.

Thus adding constructor dependencies would lead to exceptions thrown when using the Entity framework command line tooling!